# it is possible to write a page refresh code in alert box button click in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my project i'm having jquery alert box. onclicking that alert box button my page will get refreshed it is possible ?.please help me on this. oncliking the okay button my page will get refreshed.

```
     successMsg: function(msg){
    $.alert("hii");
    $.alert({
        title: 'Message:',
             type: 'green',
             columnClass: 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-3',
             content: msg,
            buttons: {

            Okay: {

                btnClass: 'btn-success',


            }


        }
```

Comment: what is `$.alert`? where is that from?

Comment: Are you just asking how to refresh a page in JavaScript?  Did you try Googling that exact phrase?

Comment: not a js. i need that in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using [the jquery-confirm.js library](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/), you should pass a callback function as a `onClose` property and call the `location.reload()` function inside it:

```js
$.alert({
  title: 'Test',
  content: 'Click "ok" to reload.',
  onClose: () => location.reload(),
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/jquery-confirm@latest"></script>
```

Comment: @santhoshithi If you already included jQuery and jquery-confirm.js, them you don't have to add these `<script>`s.

Answer (score 0):

just try simply in success block :

```
successMsg: function(msg){
     alert("test"); 
     location.reload(); //as soon as user click on OK page with reload after that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html file call ConfirmDelete function which trigger confirm alert, clicking on success it OK the page.

```js
function ConfirmDelete()
        {
          var r = confirm("Successful Message!");
           if (r == true){
             window.location.reload();
            }
            
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-1"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return ConfirmDelete()">Delete</a></div>
```